# Rendering and lighting issues in blender eevee under linux

Tags: eevee-render-engine, linux

I am experiencing some weird lighting And rendering issues on blender under Linux.

This is what I get on Linux:

[image]

And this is what I am supposed to get:

[image]

My OS is Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon with Linux kernel 5.3. iam using Blender 2.8.1 I tried loads of different Linux kernels but ended up with The same results. I tried Upgrading My kernel Downgrading My kernel. Installing Updates. I tried Everything Nothing is Working. Also I got the output when running Blender from Terminal.

```
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   182
    request code: 156
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig

Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 156
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 2, total unfreed memory 0.000458 MB

Blender quit
```

Comment: What GPU are you using? It's likely that it isn't supported or that the driver is not up-to-date.

Comment: @Robert Gutzkow Iam using Amd radeon hd 6480G And i've Updated The Mesa drivers from the update manager and iam still facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Graphics cards from the Radeon HD 6000 series are not supported, since they use the old TeraScale 2 architecture. Blender 2.8x [requires GCN first generation or later](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) when using AMD GPUs.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using the GPU requires slightly different [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). **Always make sure to install the latest drivers** from the graphics card manufacturer website.
>
> - **NVIDIA**: GeForce 200 and newer, Quadro Tesla architecture and newer, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all [GeForce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#GeForce_200_series_and_300_series) and [Quadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro#Quadro_FX_(with_CUDA_and_OpenCL,_but_no_Vulkan)) GPUs)
> - **AMD**: GCN 1st gen and newer ([list of all AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units))
> - **Intel**: Haswell and newer ([list of all Intel GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units))
> - **macOS**: version 10.12 or newer with supported hardware

Comment: Oh. Thank You for your help. This Might be the Reason but. I got blender eevee working on windows 10 with The same hardware I never Thought that changing My os Would solve the problem

Comment: It might work with the most recent graphics driver, but Blender doesn't provide support for them in case it doesn't work properly.