# Menu slider problems with Blender 2.9 on Mint Linux PC

Tags: interface

I have just downloaded Blender 2.9. I run Blender on a PC, running Mint Linux 19.3 using the 5.4.0-42 kernel. All of my menu sliders are cut off at the ends. The menus ALL show triangles or rhomboid sliders. I am including pictures as what I am trying to explain is much easier to show than to describe. Has anyone else seen this problem with a Mint Linux, or other install? Does anyone have suggestions re: How to troubleshoot the problem?

[image]

Comment: most likely an issue with the drivers for the graphics card, which, unfortunately, you don't specify. Use the proprietary drives for your card, not the open source ones.

Comment: The card is a Radeon HD 6450. I have had the card for 4 years. In all that time I have never experienced this issue through numerous iterations of Blender. But, Thank You for the suggestion :)

Comment: The Radeon HD 6450 has the TeraScale 2 micro-architecture. The [minimum requirement](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender with an AMD graphics card is GCN first generation or later. Your GPU is therefore not officially supported. It may still be possible to run Blender but graphics glitches or even crashes may occur. Sometimes such issues can be resolved by updating the graphics driver if a more recent one exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering and lighting issues in blender eevee under linux](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160278/rendering-and-lighting-issues-in-blender-eevee-under-linux)

Comment: Otherwise (as always): Menu - Help - Report a Bug.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Rather a turnabout for something that is open source. Normally this is an issue that you run into with Windows. I can still run any other application in Linux with the card... My choices seem to be; change the card, run Blender in Windows (which still works perfectly well), or use another program. It is rather sad.